# WebStorm > Import Settings issue

Tags: import, settings, webstorm

Anyone had issues in "WebStorm > Importing Settings"?

I locate `settings.zip` > Select Components to Import, click "OK" and get "Restart to Import Settings" message, click the "Import and Restart" button. WebStorm restarts but then I get no "Tools > External Tools" option after restart.

Tried Repair IDE and restarting my machine to no avail.

Comment: Where did you get that `settings.zip` from? Exported on another machine etc? What IDE version? I'm asking because there is a bug with exporting the settings in 2022.3 (the External Tools files are missing in the file). It is fixed for 2022.3.3 and the next major 2023.1 version. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-309872/Settings-Export-Settings-Tools-External-Tools-missing

Comment: P.S. If you have an access to the original machine/config you can copy the config file from there manually: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory

Comment: Thanks for your comments, decided to use VS instead.